# Is the construction of this long sentence idiomatic?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I am having a hard time trying to make this sentence grammatical, idiomatic and easily parsed; all at the same time.

> The UI program provides temporary income support to eligible unemployed workers while they actively seek new employment or obtain vocational training **[comma?]** and to those who take time off from work due to sickness, pregnancy, childbirth, or to provide care to a critically ill child or a sick family member with a significant risk of death.

1. I was told to add a comma after training. Given they are not independent clauses (one subject, *UI program*; and one verb, *provides*) I don't understand why there should be a comma.
2. I am confused about the second part. Is the usage of "or to" correct?

> "and to those who take time off from work **due to** sickness, pregnancy, childbirth, **or to** provide care..."

After trying for hours, I was suggested to use a run-in list alternative:

> The UI program provides temporary income support to **(1)** eligible unemployed workers while they actively seek new employment or obtain vocational training; and to **(2)** those who take time off from work due to sickness, pregnancy, childbirth, or to provide care to a critically ill child or a sick family member with a significant risk of death.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such information is so much more easily comprehended if you are able to break up the sentence. Unless your format excludes the sort of construction below, it's what I would suggest to you as the clearest way of communicating with your readers: (Apologies if this proves unhelpful!)

> **The UI program provides temporary income support to two groups**:
>    1.  eligible unemployed workers while they actively seek new employment or obtain vocational training;
>    2. those who take time off (from) work
>    (a) due to sickness, pregnancy or childbirth,
>    (b) to provide care to a critically ill child or a sick family member with a significant risk of death.

Comment: Thanks! Should there be a "and" after "training;"? And should there be an "or" after "childbirth,"?

Comment: In this staggered format I would say that they are optional. You could certainly put them in.